# Methods to appear and disappear objects

Tags: edit-mode, compositing-nodes

Let's think of this example (among many others).

To simplify my drop sheet and render times I have one simple (A) object for far distances, and one more complex (B) when I dolly in the camera.

Let's say on frame 150 I need to switch from object A to object B.

**What could be some methods to appear and disappear objects on an animation?**

Some examples I have used:

1. Keeping object B on a different location out of sight, anchor it at frame 150 and move it into position at frame 151. And vice-versa with object A.

One con is that If I turn on motion blur, those two frames render the motion blur.

2. Keyframing transparency.

The con is that the material gets more complex, and when overlapping with the other object in has render issues.

3. Simply rendering Roll A until frame 150, turn on and off objects, and render from frame 151 and compose later.

---

What other methods can I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is similar to your third attempt.
You can animate the viewport and render visibility.
Just hover over the 'eye' or 'camera' icon and press 'i'.
Then move to the next frame, disable both visibilites and set new keyframes. Other way around for the object that should appear.

This doesn't involve the material or messing with the motion blur.

[image]

Comment: Yes, that is my option 3 :o)

Comment: But I mean, you can render it in one go if you animate the visibility.